# connected-router error, a router may have only one child element

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}> { /* place ConnectedRouter under Provider */}
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path="/enthusiasm" component={Hello} />
          <Route exact={true} path="/shipments" component={ShipmentsTable} />
          <Route exact={true} path="/shipments/:pickUpId" component={ShipmentInfoPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

this is giving me an error saying,
`A <Router> may have only one child element, and it has only one element.`

everything is according to the example in [connected-router repo](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router#step-2)

and this was working fine with BrowserRouter, any help.

Version Info

- connected-react-router "4.4.1",
- react-router: "4.3.1",
- react: "16.4.2"

Comment: Try remove `exact` from last Route

Comment: It did not make any difference, actually I tried this with a single Route, it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is most either an error with one of the components you are rendering, or is an error with the package versions you are using.
First, I would remove your node_modules folder, next, make sure to use all the dependency versions that [this package.json file](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/package.json) is using
Next, run npm install or yarn add on your project.

If this does not work, please insert the components you are using into the origin post, especially ones that render links and routes.

Answer (score -1):

i had this issue until i change spaces to tabs. Don't know why)

Comment: This is not a answer to the question and does not help.