# React App, Browser Navigaton Management

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I have an app and I wanted to retain history when navigating.

It has a couple of lists , and lists can be filtered in a few different ways, they are not links, user types in something and hits enter or picks an option from a combobox. Switches between lists and each list has a detail component, lists get data from an API, and I wanted to provide back and forward button support for this, currently using latest versions of react and react-router-dom.

So I added redux to this, and tried to use 'connected-react-router', it made things complicated, I managed it but in the end 'connected-react-router' did not do what it was supposed to. Throws an error, maybe package versions are not aligned.
[connected-router error, a router may have only one child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834177/connected-router-error-a-router-may-have-only-one-child-element)

So my question is, can I handle this with react and react-router-dom, do I need redux, and or redux related router component like connected-react-router. Any samples for this?

Comment: If you just want to handle routing, then nope, you don't need Redux to do that. Redux is meant to manage the global state of your app, not routing.

Comment: I have actually decided to go with query part of the URL, much easier to handle.